# Why SQLite Blob type is being automatically converted in pandas Python to unicode sequence

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, blob

I have an SQLite Table with some Columns with Blob type.

The Table contains:

```
DB_Index     DB_ColumnBlob
619823       0A 00 00 00 4E 04
```

Using this code to query:

```
sql = r'''SELECT DB_ColumnBlob WHERE DB_Index = 619823'''
conn = sqlite3.connect(Settings.databasepath)
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql = sql, con = conn)
print df.iloc[0,0]
```

I get this output:

```
N z X a& + �,
```

DB_ColumnBlob contains a string of Hexadecimal digits, I want to get them as output in order to segment it in segments with 2 digits length and then convert to integer. But with the output Im getting I dont understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas or sqlite3 does not convert it to unicode (sqlite3 maps it to a python buffer object, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#introduction)), what you see is just the *default Python string repr* for a buffer object.

A small example:

```
In [46]: buffer('\x01\x42\x55')
Out[46]: <read-only buffer for 0x000000000DCCA210, size -1, offset 0 at 0x000000000DCB29D0>

In [47]: print buffer('\x01\x42\x55')
☺BU
```

As you can see, if you print the buffer, you get the string representation but it still is a buffer.
If you ask for the type of `df.iloc[0,0]` or just return it (not using print), you will see that is indeed still a buffer:

```
In [64]: df.iloc[0,0]
Out[64]: <read-write buffer ptr 0x000000000DCC9E68, size 3 at 0x000000000DCC9E30>

In [65]: type(df.iloc[0,0])
Out[65]: buffer
```